# How to get values of custom meta field of multiple arrays

Tags: wordpress, post-meta

I try to get a list for all posts of custom post type `bedrijf` from all values of a custom field. This field is an array of values. However, when I try to output the custom fields, I get

> Notice: Array to string conversion in ...

I have tried different approaches like `foreach`, `wp_pluck_list`, but so far, no success.

```
function make_list_regios(){
global $post;
$output = '<ul>';
$post_idees = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'bedrijf'));
$values = wp_list_pluck( $post_idees->posts, 'ID');
foreach( $values as $value ) {
$meta_values[] = get_post_meta( $value, 'elements', true );
            $output .= '<li>'.$meta_values.'</li>';
}

return ($output);
}
add_shortcode('regios', 'make_list_regios');
```

When I `print_r($values)`, it is an array of `post_id`. When I print out `$meta_values`, I get an array as follows:

```
Array ( [0] => [1] => Array ( [0] => groningen [1] => limburg ) [2] => [3] => [4] => Array ( [0] => noordholland [1] => zuidholland ) )
```

What I want to output is a full list of selected regions.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your array have null values and you cannot echo array element. Use json_encode

```
$output .= '<li>'.json_encode(array_filter($meta_values)).'</li>';
```

Or Implode array elements

```
$meta_values = array_filter($meta_values);
$meta_string = implode(', ', $meta_values);
$output .= '<li>'.$meta_string .'</li>';
```

Comment: Unfortunately both dont work... json_encode delivers errors in output. Array_filter does filter the empty arrays out, so one step set.

Comment: after array_filter what is the output of array?

Comment: Array ( [1] => Array ( [0] => groningen [1] => limburg ) [4] => Array ( [0] => noordholland [1] => zuidholland ) )

Answer (score 0):

With the help of @j. scott elbein i finally solved this one.
The correct code (in my case at least) is:

```
function make_list_regios(){
global $post;
$output = '<ul>';
$post_idees = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'bedrijf'));
$values = wp_list_pluck( $post_idees->posts, 'ID');
foreach( $values as $value ) {
            $meta_values[] = get_post_meta( $value, 'elements', true );
            $meta_values2 = array_filter($meta_values);
            $meta_values3 = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $meta_values2);
}
foreach($meta_values3 as $meta_value3){
            $output .='<li>'.$meta_value3.'</li>';
            }
            $output.='</ul>';
            return ($output);
}
add_shortcode('regios', 'make_list_regios');
```